# Subject verb agreement for "A greater number of"

Tags: verb-agreement, prepositional-phrases, premodifiers

What is the subject-verb agreement for the phrase "A greater number of"?

I came across this sentence and am confused.

**A greater number of cycles** with paracetamol **is** associated with increased risk of ...

Comment: "Number" is a number-transparent non-count here where agreement depends on the number of the oblique. Since "number" selects only plural obliques, the verb should be plural.  Note, though, that if "number" is preceded by "the", things are different and it takes a singular verb.

Comment: A greater number of migratory birds on the lake means clean-up efforts have been successful.  So there are your oblique birds plurally on the lake quite happy with their singular verb, because the greater number of them is a single fact from which I'm drawing a conclusion.

Comment: 'A greater number of cycles with paracetamol is associated ...' is a shorter form of 'The occurrence / administering of a greater number of cycles with paracetamol is associated ...' or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be either, depending on whether you're looking at 'one' greater number of things, or looking through it to the 'greater number' of them.

- *A greater number of students **have** phones now.*
- *A greater number of cycles per second **requires** a faster reaction time.*

In your example, use **is** if the association is with the increased *number* of cycles (it's saying that since there are more cycles, risk has also increased). If you're saying that more of those cycles are associated with the increased risk - that is, the association is between the cycles and the risks, use **are** (it's saying that more of the cycles are associated with increased risk).

Comment: You make a good point.

Comment: I don't agree. Agreement depends on the noun that is complement of "of". As it happens, "number" selects only plural obliques, so the verb should always be plural. Note that if "number"  is preceded by "the", things are different and it takes a singular verb.

Comment: @BillJ Your statement was exactly my doubt.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you. Your answer gave me pause, though. I was focusing on the 'greater' part and hadn't fully considered the case with a bare 'number'.

Comment: @BillJ If we generalise your 'the' proviso to 'any determiner' (such as 'greater'), we'd agree on the *reaction time* example. But we might then disagree on the *phone* example.

Answer (score -1):

Most people would say *are* there so that the cycles are the risk, because normally *a number of* counts as a premodifier the same way *a lot of* or *a great many* does, and such things no more count for determining whether the verb should be singular or plural than the word *some* would.

#### Right

1. A number of my **friends have** told me **they’re** coming.

#### Wrong

2. A number of my friends *has told me they’re coming.
3. A number of my friends *has told me *he’s coming.
4. A number of my friends *has told me *it’s coming.

I’ve prefixed each wrong word above with an asterisk.