# A finite or infinite amount plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number

Should it be:

Are there a finite or infinite number of them?

or

Is there a finite or infinite number of them?

I found that 'a number of' is should have a plural verb, e.g., there are a number of problems, but I'm unsure about what happens after adding finite or infinite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subject verb agreement for "A greater number of"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424197/subject-verb-agreement-for-a-greater-number-of)

Comment: "There **are** a finite or infinite number of **them**?" ~ "**Are** there a finite or infinitive number of **them**?" Incidentally, "number" takes plural agreement when it has "a" as determiner, but singular agreement with "the" by virtue of having singular non-transparent "number" as head.